# Django serve views asynchronously

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, coroutine, asgi

Django 3.2.8 (a relatively old version)

```py
@csrf_exempt
def xhrView(request, ms, status=200):
    sleep(ms / 1000)
    response = HttpResponse(
        f'{status} DUMMYXHRRESPONSE IN {ms}ms'
    )
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.status_code = status
    return response
```

I am hosting an api server for generative data testing with django.

I have views for example serving purposes like:

1. fetch or xhr js test
2. generate fake json based on api query
3. generate random long text

but due to the python lang nature `GIL`, django is not capable of serving views asynchronously, which for example,
if userA is visitng `xhr/10000`, any other user won't be able to even access the server in that duration.

in those api views I don't need to access database, is there a way to serve the view above asynchronously?

> p.s. I have channels installed and is using websocket somewhere else for social messaging, the proj is set to asgi.

---

I have tried

> `consumers.py`

```py
import asyncio
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from channels.generic.http import AsyncHttpConsumer
from django.http import HttpResponse

class XhrConsumer(AsyncHttpConsumer):
    @database_sync_to_async
    def sleep_ms(self, ms):
        return asyncio.sleep(ms / 1000)

    async def handle(self, body):
        ms = int(self.scope['url_route']['kwargs'].get('ms', 0))
        await self.sleep_ms(ms)
        response = HttpResponse(f'{self.get_status()} DUMMYXHRRESPONSE IN {ms}ms')
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        await self.send_response(response)

    def get_status(self):
        return getattr(self, 'status', 200)  # Default status is 200
```

> `asgi.py`

```
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": django_asgi_app,
  "websocket": URLRouter(
    [path('xhr/<int:ms>/', XhrConsumer.as_asgi())],   
  )
})
```

but http://127.0.0.1:8000/xhr/10000 is not accessible. I am certain that asgi is set properly since all my other notification and messaging functionality has passed unit test.

Comment: "but due to the python lang nature GIL, django is not capable of serving views asynchronously" – what? Your view isn't `async`, and you're not telling us how you're running your application either. If you have a single-threaded, single-process ASGI server, it will of course only serve one synchronous request at a time.

Comment: @AKX, Oh i just leaned `python manage.py runserver` uses the development server provided by Django, which is a single-threaded server and does not provide built-in support for ASGI or asynchronous processing. Therefore, running the development server alone will not allow my views to be served asynchronously using ASGI. I will install Daphne then I reckon asgi is able to serve views asynchronously since then I guess? ^v^

Comment: Async views, sure - but what you have is not an async view. It's a plain function that will block the thread executing it for the duration of the sleep.

Comment: @AKX, Does that mean I simply add a async statement before every view function, and serve it with urlpatterns not `URLRounter` as usual, then it will be served as async? (meanwhile avoid using `time.sleep`, switch to something like `asyncio.sleep`)

Comment: No. (a) You'll need to read up on Django's async views work. (b) Any synchronous calls within your async views will still block the executor running them.